# Inheritance Mapping in EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, mapping

I have a class inheritting from another class based on 2 discriminators.

I want to do something like:

```
Map<FineStatusTypePaidFull>(
  m => m.Requires("LookupKey")
        .HasValue("FineStatusType") && ("LookupCode")
        .HasValue("PIF");
```

But I have not found anything yet.... any suggestions?

Comment: There is something wrong with this code - what is LookupCode? Can you add more description of what you are trying to achieve instead of a code snippet that is not really parsable and can lead to different interpretations of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have class FineStatusTypePaidFull that inherits from class Lookup. This inheritance should be based on the values of 2 fields in our LookupTable: LookupKey and LookupCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the following link. Appearantly the bug is not fixed yet in EF 5.0

[Entity Framework 4.3 - TPH mapping and migration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499702/entity-framework-4-3-tph-mapping-and-migration-error/12737082#12737082)

Comment: I tried, it fixed in the Nuget latest EF 4.4 (.NET 4.0) which should be the same with EF 5 (.NET 4.5)